# site.css not found in .NET 6 Web App with custom environment

Tags: css, .net, web, .net-6.0

Using the latest default web app template, e.g. `dotnet new blazorserver`, if I change my environment from `Development` to, say, `LocalDevelopment`, debugging locally I lose all my styling because my site.css file will not be found (we use this custom environment when debugging locally, to differentiate from running on our shared Development web server.)

I believe this is because, per the docs,

> static web assets are enabled by default in the Development environment. To support assets in other environments when running from build output, call `UseStaticWebAssets` on the host builder in `Program.cs`.

One way to do this, using the .NET 3.1/5 style hosting model, is as follows, to enable UseStaticWebAssets:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets();
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

My question is, how do I accomplish this using the .NET 6 style hosting model?  We want to use the new model for all our new apps.  I've tried the following:

```
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
```

This yields this exception:

> The web root changed from "C:\Web\BlazorServerApp\wwwroot" to "C:\Web\BlazorServerApp\". Changing the host configuration using WebApplicationBuilder.WebHost is not supported. Use WebApplication.CreateBuilder(WebApplicationOptions) instead.

and I've tried this:

```
builder.Host.ConfigureWebHost(c => c.UseStaticWebAssets());
```

and I've even tried this,

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    WebRootPath = "wwwroot"
});
```

This last bit of code seems to do the opposite of the intention; the root of the app seems to be set to `/` rather than the intended `wwwroot`, because in the browser debug window it seems to be looking for `/site.css` rather than `wwwroot/site.css`.

Is there any way, using the new .NET 6 hosting model / minimal templates, to enable using StaticWebAssets in a custom environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that was brutal...I tried all the same with no luck, but this worked --

```
[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(HelloCoreSix.MyAppHostingStartup))]

namespace HelloCoreSix
{
    public class MyAppHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.UseStaticWebAssets();
        }
    }
}
```

Drop the above in a .cs file, it'll get picked up during bootstrap.

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is obvious: you should set Web Root Path back to "wwwroot":

```
builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot("wwwroot");
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
```

or

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(
    new WebApplicationOptions
    {
        Args = args,
        WebRootPath = "webroot"
    }
);
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
```

I don't know the "right" way for .Net 6, but it works

Comment: If you read my question, I’ve already tried those things, and they don’t work.

Comment: I've just tested it with blazorserver template, and both snippets does work in Production mode

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Production mode" but as I mentioned in my question, this is about debugging locally.  Running in Production, or deployed on any server after ```dotnet publish```, it works fine.  I'd like my .css styling to work while debugging, with a custom environment, using .NET 6 hosting model.

Comment: I mean running .Net Web App from its project folder (either from VS or from command-line) with ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production